# How to push elements to a multi dimensional array in a loop(javascript)?

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I am parsing JSON data and retrieving 3 values in each node,

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function (key, val) {
    Var X = val.date;
    Var y = val.type;
    Var z = val.text;
});
```

Example JSON data

```
val.date= '2011/02/09', val.type=3, val.text = 'Some text'
```

I wanna store these values in a array as in

```
var arrA = new Array();
arrA[0] = new Array(X,Y,Z);
arrA[1] = new Array(X,Y,Z); etc
```

WHere X,Y,Z changesfor every node in JSON data.
At the end of which my arrA should contain the following data

```
['2011/02/09', 3, 'Some text'],
['2011/12/11', 3, 'something to show']
.
.
.
['2011/02/08,3,'something else']
```

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: Can you post an example of the json data you will be working with?

Comment: Hi, I have out the sample JSON data in my question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arrA = new Array();

$.each($.parseJSON(data), function (key, val) {
    arrA.push([val.date, val.type, val.text]);
}
```